# When would "mom/dad" require capital letter in writing?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, proper-nouns

I understand the capitalization rule for nouns, proper nouns require a capital letter. Also, I should begin a new sentence with a capital letter.

**When & why "mom/dad" requires a capital letter** ?

(Reference- ELL- [I am at Vapi where mom is hospitalised](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59576/i-am-at-vapi-now-as-mom-is-hospitalised-now-is-this-correct))

> **mom**:
>
> (n) informal term for a mother/North American term for mum.

Comment: The link is broken.  Was it pasted accurately?

Comment: this is an ELL question. why is it here and getting answers?

Comment: @JoeBlow Well, this is embarrassing; I'm a native speaker, but I don't write those two words often enough to have thought about their capitalization before. So, to me, it's worth reviewing. However, it's also a duplicate, so it probably should be closed regardless.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When it is their name, Mom and Dad would be capitalised:

> Dear Mom and Dad,
>   I am just writing to let you know, that although everyone has a mom and a  >dad, you are my special mom and dad. So, Mom,
>   I just want to say ‘brava!’; and Dad, ‘bravo!’. I’ve just been telling
>   Sis, that Mom’s new coat is so cool.  XX

Here's the commentary from an exercise from [BBC English on Line](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/learningenglish/2011/11/capitalisation.shtml)

> *...to have a roast chicken lunch with my mother. I can't wait!* - mother
>   does not need a capital 'M' as it is not being used to replace her
>   name. If I said, "I am going to lunch with Mum", it would need a
>   capital letter, but "I am going to lunch with my mum" does not.

Comment: @Hugh, A simple ELL question but I did not think about their capitalization before. But thank you for the clarification which is only possible at ELU.

Answer (score 15):

> We should capitalize *these words* if they are being used as **the
>   name of the person**. You can capitalize these when [referring to your
>   own relatives](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g71.html): Hello, Mother.

- When you use mom/dad in general meaning father/mother, it's a common
  noun. So do not capitalize them when they follow possessive pronouns such as her, his, my, our, your.
  (my mother ~ my mom )
- [A good rule to follow is to capitalize them if they are used as     proper nouns.](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g71.html)  (dictionary.com)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, a difficult choice for the best answer.